# Compile some C code to extend PostGIS extension on Windows

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have some C code that is used on a Ubuntu server to create some extension to PostGIS. Now I want to install those functions on my Windows server (Where I now want to run my PostgreSQL server from). I manage to setup one Visual Studio solution but I got a lot of failing includes.

I downloaded the PostGIS and PostgreSQL source code and included them in the Visual Studio solution dependencies. However, I can't find the `liblwgeom.h` to be able to use `POINT2D` etc. From what I understood I need to build PostGIS as well in order to generate that file or where is it located in PostGIS 3.3.2 source code?

If I need to build PostGIS in order to get it, is there any updated guide or advice how to build it in a Windows environment?

Comment: The dependency chains required to compile a PostgreSQL extension are on the ragged edge of GIS-centric, even if that extension is PostGIS.  You might find more developer support in [so] proper.